# MvxGridView - crash when item template is set

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I tried to use `Mvx.MvxGridView` but it crash when I set `MvxItemTemplate` with debug output message:

```
Could not find method android.widget.GridView.<init>, referenced from method cirrious.mvvmcross.binding.droid.views.MvxGridView.<init>
```

Crashing code:

```
  <Mvx.MvxGridView
android:id="@+id/GridView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
local:MvxBind="ItemsSource SomeSource"
local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/itemtemplatepath"/>
```

Item template:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/MyApp.Droid">
  <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="0"
      android:gravity="top|center"
      local:MvxBind="Text Member.FirstName"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</LinearLayout>
```

If `MvxItemTemplate` isn't set - then `MvxGridView` is rendered with default ItemTemplate (text with full class name). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok my fault - it works but `LinearLayout` (every defined View) should have  explicitly set "`android:layout_width`" and "`android:layout_height".`